# Reusable WebDriverWait problem "object has no attribute 'driver'"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a reusable Wait but keep getting this error    `WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'driver'`

My code:

In Browser.Py I have

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class Browser(object):

 def wait_for(self, locator):
     WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
```

And I try calling it by:

```
from features.browser import Browser
from features.locators import Locators
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

class Steps(Browser):

    def delete_from_cart2(self):
        Browser.wait_for(*Locators.DELETE_FROM_CART2)
```

Comment: ```self.driver```is not defined anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

`wait_for` could be like this

```
def wait_for(self, driver, locator):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
```

and driver instance can be passed on to the variable.